# rails - find joining multiple fields under different names

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have these two tables

tickets - id, user_id, manager_id etc

users - id, first_name etc

user_id and manager_id are both references for users

using rails is there a way of creating a find that pulls in the users info and managers(users) info.

The sql joins would look abit like this -

```
LEFT JOIN users ON users.id = tickets.user_id

LEFT JOIN users as managers ON managers.id = tickets.manager_id
```

Expected result

```
ticket:
  subject: something interesting
  user_id: 1
  manager_id: 3
  user:
   id: 1
   name: Frank
  manager:
   id: 3
   name: Alex
```

Thanks, Alex

Comment: Is this Rails 2 or 3?  What are the relationships defined in the Ticket and User models?

Comment: rails 3. user has_many :tickets, tickets belongs_to :users

Comment: Could you explain in a meta-way, what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: You want to find User and Manager information by looking up tickets? I can't figure out what you're trying to accomplish as a story.

Comment: I have added what the result should look like

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, you should use something like:

```
class Ticket < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :user
   belongs_to :manager, :class_name => "User"
end

class Ticket < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :tickets
end
```

Then you can use

```
@ticket = Ticket.first
@ticket.user.name    >> "Frank"
@ticket.manager.name >> "Alex"
```

Answer (score 0):

Your models should be set up as this :

```
#ticket.rb
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :manager

#manager.rb
has_many :tickets

#user.rb
has_many :tickets
```

Examples of finds (still not sure how you want to set up your find ):

```
Ticket.find(x)
Ticket.all.select{|t|t.manager_id == @manager.id}
Ticket.find(:all, :conditions => 'manager_id="@manager.id"')
```